# Collapsible only works once (NOT BOOTSTRAP)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm not using bootstrap for this project. I made a collapsible paragraph with some help from w3schools, but the problem I'm facing is it works only once. I'm not sure why

```js
var coll = $("#aboutUsCollapsible");
var tmp = $("#mainCollapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.previousElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = 0;
      tmp.show();
    } else {
      tmp.hide();
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapsible" id="mainCollapsible">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>

<div class="collapsible-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>

<a class="button" id="aboutUsCollapsible">Learn More</a>
```

**Codepen**
https://codepen.io/amrh910/pen/KKgZEdy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check for `content.style.maxHeight` it should look like this:

```
if (content.style.maxHeight !== "" && content.style.maxHeight !== "0px") {
```